# Elasticsearch query on apostrophes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am querying on elasticsearch the query is **apples**. In our index data, the text is presented like **apple's**. If I search like **apples** I got no results. If I searched for **apple's** we got results. But in my concern, if I search with **apples** also I need same results for **apple's** query. Is there any way to handle these type of cases.

Comment: so you want to catch both **apples** and both **apple's**?

Comment: Yes, whenever I am querying for apples. I want the results for both apples and apple's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a char_filter set in the following way:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
    },
    "char_filter": {
      "my_char_filter": {
        "type": "mapping",
        "mappings": [
          "' => "
        ]
       }
      } 
    }
  }
}


POST my_index/_analyze
{
 "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
 "text": "apple's"
}
```

This will result in:

```
{
  "tokens": [
  {
    "token": "apples",
    "start_offset": 0,
    "end_offset": 7,
    "type": "word",
    "position": 0
  }
 ]
}
```

You are removing apostrophe from index and you can search successfully for both **apples** and **apple's**

Comment: This is a good answer. OP might also consider english [language analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html) -- if they would also want to match singular nouns as well ("apple").

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you need a **fuzzy search**, if I got your point right. Please give a look on this article: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search and let know, if that isn't what you're looking for.